# Passing a task as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, .net-4.5

I am not sure whether this is possible, so here me out:

I have a sequence of action to perform multiple

```
async Task MethodA(...)
{
    // some code
    // a call to specific Async IO bound method
    // some code
}
```

there are also `MethodB()`, `MethodC()`, etc, and all of the have exactly the same code, except for the call to specific Async IO bound method. I am trying to find a way to pass a task pointer to a method, so that we can execute it later in a Method().

What i am currently doing is this:

```
private async Task Method(Func<Task<Entity>> func)
{
    // some code
    var a = await task.Run(func);
    // some code
}

var task = async () => await CallToIOBoundTask(params);
Method(task);
```

This code, however, pulls a new thread each time, which is not required for IO bound task, and should be avoided.

So, is there a way to refactor the code so that no ThreadPool thread is used? A goal is to have a code like this:

```
private async Task Method(Task<Entity> task)
{
    // some code
    var a = await task;
    // some code
}
```

It is also important to mention that different IO calls have different method signatures. Also, a task can start to execute only in `Method()` body, and not before.

Comment: Do you want to wait until the statement in the `Method()` method for the async task to begin? If so, then your code example in the question is incorrect (awaiting an _existing_ task instead of creating one), and the answer already provided is what you want. But if you just want to be able to await a task you've started before the `Method()` method is called, note that you can easily do that: just call e.g. pass the return value of a call to `CallToIOBoundTask()` as the argument for your call to the `Method()` method.

Comment: @PeterDuniho An answer to your question is in the last sentence of the question - Task needs to start its execution in method().

Comment: Is there a way to do this but where I am wanting to have `var myParam = "test"; var a = await task(myParam);` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Of course, simply invoke the `func`, get back a task, and `await` it:

```
async Task Method(Func<Task<Entity>> func)
{
    // some code
    var a = await func();
    // some code
}
```

Also, when you're sending that lambda expression, since all it's doing is calling an `async` method which in itself returns a task, it doesn't need to be `async` in itself:

```
Method(() => CallToIOBoundTask(params));
```

That's fine as long as all these calls return `Task<Entity>`. If not, you can only use `Task` (which means starting the operation and awaiting its completion) and you won't be able to use the result.

Comment: Heh, I tried without the parentheses, and it did  not work. :) AS for your 2nd suggestion, what will the IL generate for this part: () => CallToIOBoundTask(params)? Will that be an async Task Method or not? I cannot have this code to be generated as void.

Comment: @Goran It will not be an `async` method. But it will return a task since `CallToIOBoundTask` returns a task. Also, it can't be void since the parameter is not an `Action` but `Func<Task<Entity>>`. If you want to make sure you can expand that lambda to `() => { return CallToIOBoundTask(params); }` which is exactly the same.